# Javascript - how can I write a recursive function to build an array of strings like wordwrap?

Tags: javascript, string, recursion

I need to build an array of strings line by line. It will be like wordwrap.

I will have input text like this:

```
    var inputString = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration';
```

I need each line in my array to be a max of 38 characters. I don't want to split any words in the middle so if the 38 characters is in the middle of a word then go back to the nearest space character.

Desired output:

```
    var output = [
        'There are many variations of passages',
        'of Lorem Ipsum available, but the',
        'majority have suffered alteration'
    ];
```

Incorrect output:

```
'There are many variations of passages '
'of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majo'
'rity have suffered alteration.'
```

I have tried to split the input text by the space character to end up with this:

```
var splitInput = [
'There',
'are',
'many'
...
] 


  function conc(arguments){
        if (arguments.length === 0) 
            return "";
        else 
            return arguments.shift() + conc(arguments);
}
```

I am not sure how I can check if the arguments total 38 or more and then backtrack if they do.

Answer (score 5):

you can use string.prototype.match() to do that

```js
    var inputString = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration';


let result = inputString.match(/\b.{1,38}\b/g);

console.log(result);
```

since regex would be non overlapping, you would get the desired result

Comment: Just a note: `\b` is not Unicode aware, and if the text contains non-ASCII letters, the words might still get split in halves.

Comment: That's a great answer but the empty string in the last item is not desired.

Comment: updated the answer to have atleast 1 character match

Comment: What happens if there is an edge case where the first word is 38 chars?

Comment: It would have a array of length 1 as the output

Comment: First word is more than 38 chars? non-English language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` in javascript for length `38` and splitting the string.

```js
 var inputString = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration';
var result = inputString.replace(/.{38}\S*\s+/g, "$&@").split(/\s+@/);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without using recursion:

```
var inputString = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration';
var splitted = inputString.split(" ");
var output = [""];
var i = 0;
splitted.forEach(word => {
   var line = output[i] + " " +  word; 
   if (line.length <= 38) {
       output[i] = line;
   } else {
       i++;
       output[i] = word;
   }
});
console.log("Output:", output);
```